# Loop Turning into an Infinite Loop

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, nodes

A segment of my code is triggering an infinite while loop, and I'm not sure why. I've used the loop itself before to add friends to a Linked List in this same program and it worked fine, so I do not understand why it is turning into an infinite loop now.

```
while (!a.equals("*")){

   curr = friendlist.getUsers().getFront();

   while (curr!=null){

      if (curr.getData().getName().equals(a)){ //why is it not removing friends?
         d.removeFriend(curr.getData());
      }

      curr = curr.getNext();
   }

   System.out.println("Add a friend by typing in their name. Enter * to end. ");
   a = in.nextLine();
}
```

The above code accesses the following segment from another class:

```
public void removeFriend(User u){
    if (friendsList.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Empty list, cannot remove.");
    }
    else{
        Node c = friendsList.getFront();
        while (c.getNext()!=null){
            if (c.getNext().getData().equals(u)){ //condition: if the data is the same
                c.setNext(c.getNext().getNext()); //change the link
                c.getNext().setData(null); //set the next data to null (cut the link)
                friendsList.setSize(friendsList.size()-1);
                c = c.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the code not running properly?

Comment: Do not use variable names `a` and `c`.  Use meaningful variable names like `frontNode` and `currentUser`

Comment: How are your code segments linked to each other? I do not see a call to `oldestFriend()` in the first half.

Comment: I copy-pasted the wrong code in, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As another poster has mentioned, you are invoking the `getNext()` method twice in one code block.

Here's what I presume is what will work for you

```
while (c!=null){
    if (c.getNext().getData().oldestFriend().getBirthYear()>c.getData().oldestFriend().getBirthYear()){
        a = c.getNext().getData();
        continue;  //then skip the current iteration, so that your line below after the if statement, wont get called.
    }
    c = c.getNext();
}
```

Why dont you do this, because now it looks like you're calling that same method three times!

Instead, store whatever is returned from the `getNext()` into one variable, and then access that local variable and do whatever you want with it, analyse is however you like etc.

Answer (score 0):

change your `while` by:

```
while (c.hasNext() {
    Node oldC = c; 
    c = c.getNext();
    if(c.getData().oldestFriend().getBirthYear() > oldC.getData().oldestFriend().getBirthYear()) {
        a = c.getData();
    }
}
```

Call only `getNext()` if there is next, and only once.

Comment: Do you also see a comparison between two identical fields? Just wondered about... So the `if` will never be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where the infinite loop is exactly? Maybe put a `System.out.println("loop")` before `curr.getNext()` and `c.getNext()` so see which one is failing?

Would add this as a comment, but I'm not yet allowed to :(

Answer (score 0):

How is the semantic of

```
allUsers.getFront()
```

Does it just fetch the head or is it more like a pop-operation?

In case of a fetch, there might be an issue with the recursive call of

```
oldestFriend()
```

in the method oldestFriend().

Though in that case I would expect a StackOverflowException.